# [[ BASH ]] How to operate string lines if pattern is found

Tags: bash, shell

Good day,

I was wondering how to substitute all `\n` with a whitespace between the same pattern:

```
PATTERN
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM \n
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM \n
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM \n
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM \n
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM \n
PATTERN
```

To obtain:

```
PATTERN
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM ..................
PATTERN
```

So far I have done `sed -e '/PATTERN/s/\n/ /g'`

Thanks so much in advance for any clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/PATTERN/{if(f){print ""};print;f=f?0:1;next}f{printf "%s ", $0}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
PATTERN
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
PATTERN
$ awk '/PATTERN/{if(f){print ""};print;f=f?0:1;next}f{printf "%s ", $0}' file
PATTERN
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
PATTERN
```

Using `gnu-sed`:

```
$ sed '/PATTERN/b;:a;N;/PATTERN/b;s/\n/ /;ba' file
PATTERN
LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
PATTERN
```

Comment: hehehe ... you are a genius! Thanks so much... how have you learnt bash at that level?

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you for the kind words. Just kept practicing here by answering questions. People here are very helpful. They will correct your answer, suggest alternates even explain the pitfalls. So got little better over time. BTW added a `gnu-sed` option too. `:)`

Comment: Thanks so much and that is true, only by practicing, a person become wise `:)`